# Is it possible to display the entity &#8659; in IE6

Tags: internet-explorer-6

is it possible to display ⇓ entity in ie6? It is being display in every browser but not IE 6.I am writing markup such as:

```
<span>&#8659;</span>
```

Comment: you can write &amp; in place of the ampersand instead of escaping the code in your example

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [this page](https://web.archive.org/web/20080221144246/http://www.ackadia.com:80/web-design/character-code/character-code-symbols.php), that symbol doesn't show in IE6 at all.

```
Symbol  Character  Numeric  Description
⇓       &dArr;     &#8659;  Down double arrow - -  * Doesn't show with MS IE6
```

If you really need that particular symbol, you may just have to go for a small graphic of the arrow - not an ideal solution, but if you need it to display in IE6 then that may be your only option.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is possible... But you'll need to explicitly tell IE which font to find it in. For instance:

```
<span style="font-family:Arial Unicode MS"> &#8659; </span>
```

should produce  ⇓  in most browsers.